# Assigning Teams Randomly on Jython

Tags: jython

I need to write a function that randomly assigns names I put in a parameter to teams I put in another parameter. The function name looks like: def random(team,name)
and it should come out like this:
def random(["blue","russia","hat"],["bob","sue","kim"])

bob is on the russia team
sue is on the hat team
kim is on the blue team

Answer (score 0):

At first do not use `random` for function name. It is standard Python module name and you should read about this module. In `random` module you can find `choice()` function which you can use like this:

```
def print_random_team(teams, names):
    for name in names:
        team = random.choice(teams)
        print('%s is on the %s team' % (name, team))


print_random_team(["blue","russia","hat"],["bob","sue","kim"])
```